# optiongroup value change listener triggered on setItemdatasource

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

i have a form with an option group, textfields, comboboxes and so on. the form is bound to a certain dataset of a table. every time i navigate through the table datasets the form datasource is set.

now the important part: iam curious why the valuechange listener of the optiongroup is triggered through setItemDatasource (if the value of the option group changes)? Is it a vaadin bug? How can i solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It does usually trigger the value change listeners on all associated controls, not only optiongroup. So either register the listeners afterwards, or ignore this in the event listener with some class-global flag or similar.

Comment: thanks. i solved it with a flag. It's still strange though, that it only happens with the optiongroup.